# Add text color while print - Python

Tags: python, jtextcomponent

I want to add text color while print output. How to do that ?

Example: `Print('Hello Everyone.')` I want output text
 `Hello Everyone` will highlighted red color.

Thanks you!

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/287871/how-to-print-colored-text-in-terminal-in-python

Comment: I have read this topic and tried something but fail :)

Comment: Did you try the [termcolor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/293633/12288654) package? I know that works well.

Comment: Yes... I have installed it before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy way to do this is to import a color module like colorama or termcolor. This site might be useful: [Print Colors in Python terminal](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-colors-python-terminal/). For you code it would be:

```
from colorama import Fore
print(Fore.RED + 'Hello Everyone')
```

or

```
import sys 
from termcolor import colored, cprint
print(colored('Hello Everyone', 'red'))  # method one
cprint('Hello Everyone', 'red')          # method two
```

Comment: Thanks you.. I have installed colored & cprint…. but when print ouput, the result : [31mHello Everyone[0m

Comment: Hi @WangGang. How to add text color into userinput: userinput = input('You: ').upper()

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
class bcolors:
    HEADER = '\033[95m'
    OKBLUE = '\033[94m'
    OKGREEN = '\033[92m'
    WARNING = '\033[93m'
    FAIL = '\033[91m'
    ENDC = '\033[0m'
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    UNDERLINE = '\033[4m'

print(bcolors.OKGREEN + 'Hello Everyone')
```

Comment: Thanks you. I have tried : from colorama import init
from termcolor import colored
init()

Comment: Hi @krishna . How to add text color into userinput:   userinput = input('You: ').upper()